# Android Studio: Virtual Device

Tags: java, android

When I run my app, my virtual device is stuck on a loading screen, which I presume is the fragment that I implemented  on my main activity. This fragment only contains a list of three items.

**Java Code:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roomiemenu,container,false);
    String[] menu = {"Manage Roomies","Calender","Transfers"};
    ListAdapter menuAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu);
    ListView roomieLM = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.roomieLM);
    roomieLM.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only layout inflate in onCreateView() method. And create adapter and set it to list inside onActivityCreated().